# Simple Pytorch LSTM model not learning for counterfactual creation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, lstm

I am building a LSTM in Pytorch to create a counterfactual forecast of a waterflow timeseries. To predict waterflow at day i ($\hat{y}_i$), my feature set $X_i$ is comprises of weather data from the same day, as well as from past days. Other models have learned the signal very well (i.e. LGBM), and even with a penalised regression, the feature set explains most of the variation in waterflow.

Nevertheless, the LSTM doesn't seem to learn much but the average. Is it something with how I'm passing the data during learning?

(discard the hyper-parameters, that are initialised somewhat randomly. I will use optuna to optimise that at a later stage)

Thank you so much for any help!

Code:

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device)
        
        # print(f"x size at the start of lstm call: {x.size()}")

        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))

        # print(f"x size at the start of forward call: {x.size()}")
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])  # take the last time-step's output
        return out

dta = "../ml_dataset_Jan24.dta"

data = pd.read_stata(dta)

data['datetime'] = data.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(f"{int(x['year'])}-{int(x['month'])}-{int(x['day'])}", format='%Y-%m-%d'), axis=1)
data.set_index('datetime', drop=True, inplace=True)
data.drop(columns=['year','month', 'day'], inplace=True)

# create feature and target sets 
X_train = data.loc[(data.index>'1990-12-31') & (data.index<'2006-01-01'), data.columns != 'level_cs'].values
y_train = data.loc[(data.index>'1990-12-31') & (data.index<'2006-01-01'), 'level_cs'].values


X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1])
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0], 1, 1)


X = torch.from_numpy(X_train).float()
y = torch.from_numpy(y_train).float()


# Define hyperparameters
input_size = 1332  # Number of features
hidden_size = 128
num_layers = 5
output_size = 1

# Define the device to train on (CPU or GPU)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Instantiate model
model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, output_size).to(device)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Train  model
num_epochs = 500
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    #  print(f'X size: ', X.size())
    outputs = model(X.to(device))
    loss = criterion(outputs, y.to(device))
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

# Set the model to evaluation mode
model.eval()

# Inference
# with torch.no_grad():
#     predictions = model(X_test.to(device))

# print("Sample Predictions:", predictions)`
```

[Y_test predictions are basically just an average](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UDCP.png)

I passed the data in one batch, with the Y_train being the same timestamps as the the ones in X_train, since I want to use data from date 'i' to predict waterflow 'i'. The feature set also includes past weather data, and I am unsure whether that should be the case, or whether the importance of that data will be retained by the memory mechanism